# Why does moving the `.exe` file circumvent Windows Security's "Your Internet security settings prevented one or more files from being opened"?

Tags: windows-7, security, internet-explorer

I have downloaded an archive with Google Chrome on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. I uncompressed it: amongst the uncompressed there is an `.exe` file.  When I try to run it by double clicking on the file in windows explorer, it says "Your Internet security settings prevented one or more files from being opened", and it prevents the `.exe` from running:

[image]

If I move the `.exe` file to a different folder, I don't have this Windows Security message. Why does moving the `.exe` file fixed the issue?

---

I'm aware that I can follow the instructions on   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2588679/error-message-when-you-try-to-open-certain-files-in-windows-7-your-int to prevent Windows Security from blocking the `.exe` in the first place:

> Method 1: Reset Internet Explorer security zone settings to their default level
>
> To reset Internet Explorer security zone settings to their default level, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Start Internet Explorer.
> 2. Click Tools, and then click Internet options.
> 3. Click the Security tab.
> 4. Click Reset all zones to default level, and then click OK.
>
> Method 2: Reset Internet Explorer settings
>
> To learn how to reset Internet Explorer settings, click the following
> article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
> [How to reset Internet Explorer
> settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings):
>
> 1. Close all Internet Explorer windows. Select the Tools  button, and then select Internet options.
> 2. Select the Advanced tab, and then select Reset.
> 3. In the Reset Internet Explorer Settings dialog box, select Reset.
> 4. When Internet Explorer finishes applying default settings, select Close, and then select OK. Restart your PC to apply changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is exactly the complete initial file path ? C:\Users\your_username... and ?

I suspect the file path is too long, this is a known issue leading to the same message box.
To test if this is the cause, you can try to create a new hierarchy of folders with same path length and copy your file in it. For instance :

`C:\test123456789012345678901234567890\test123456789012345678901234567890\...`

If you get the same message box, then this was the cause.

Comment: So, was excessive path length the actual reason? The info that Windows uses to throw up those security warnings is carried in an "alternate data stream" in the file. That ADS can be lost by copying to a non-NTFS filesystem, or by using benighted software to copy, and so on.

Comment: @kreemoweet correct, excessive path length was the reason. I could check it by trying to rename the file: Windows explorer wouldn't let me as the filepath was too long. I instead unzipped using "unzip here", resulting in shorter filepath, and it worked. Hard to believe I know